# How to import plotly on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Hi I was trying to import `plotly` on GoogleColab.

I used the code `import plotly.plotly as py import plotly.graph_objs as go` and it returns

```
ImportError: The plotly.plotly module is deprecated, please install the chart-studio package and use the chart_studio.plotly module instead.
```

Can someone shed a bit light on this please? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `sklearn` already installed?

Comment: As @GZ0 said, it's already installed. Just use `import sklearn` and it's all yours.

Comment: Second of all, when you are trying to install something using pip on Google Colab, use `!` before pip like so `!pip install [module]`

Comment: I ran `from sklearn import decomposition
` and it returned `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' ` that's why I am not sure it's there

Comment: How do you run it in PyCharm?

Comment: That's not Colab, you are running this locally... there is `PyCharm` in the returned trace

Comment: Yeah sorry I realise that was a mistake.. I actually wanted to ask why `import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go` returns `ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead. ` and how to fix that... Thanks

Comment: @GZ0  Anwarvic thanks for your help, i've changed the question now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the error says, try installing `chart-sudio` using:

```
!pip install chart_studio
```

Then import it like so:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your code, i tried to run it but the result is the same

Comment: I've provided a screenshot... Try to do exactly like I did?

Comment: Worked now! Thanks! Is chart_studio.plotly different from plotly?

Comment: Glad I could help :)... And No, they just changed the package name from `plotly` to `chart-studio `

Answer (score 2):

Plotly has been updated. Try this:

```
import plotly.express as px
```